# jQuery Datatables AJAX request not hitting Web API correctly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, datatables

I am trying to integrate **ASP.NET Web API 2** with **jQuery Datatables 1.10.7**.

I want to use Server Side processing in my Datatables, so I am used the Nuget package **DataTables.AspNet.WebApi2**

Here is my javascript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "/api/StudentsBasicInfo/GetPaginatedStudentsList2",
            columns: [
            {
                name: 'FirstName',
                data: 'FirstName',
                title: "First Name",
                sortable: false,
                searchable: false
            },
            {
                name: 'LastName',
                data: "LastName",
                title: "Last Name",
                sortable: false,
                searchable: false
            }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my HTML

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
</table>
```

Here is my Web API

```
    public JsonResult<IDataTablesResponse> GetPaginatedStudentsList2(IDataTablesRequest request)
    {
        StudentsInfoHybrid searchObj = new StudentsInfoHybrid();

        StudentsBasicInfoBL blClass = new StudentsBasicInfoBL();

        try
        {
            searchObj.PageSize = request.Length;
            searchObj.Offset = request.Start;
            searchObj.count = false;

            //get the list of students
            var students = blClass.GetAllStudentsHybridInfo(searchObj);

            //filter list according to the criteria passed in the request object
            var filteredStudents = students.Where(i => i.FirstName.Contains(request.Search.Value)).ToList();

            //reset page size and offset so that count of total objects can be obtained
            searchObj.PageSize = 0;
            searchObj.Offset = 0;

            var totalCount = blClass.CountAllStudentsHybridInfo(searchObj);

            var response = DataTablesResponse.Create(request, students.Count(), filteredStudents.Count(), filteredStudents);

            return new DataTablesJsonResult(response, Request);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        { }
    }
```

My code builds perfectly, but during execution when datatable calls the Web API, I can see in Debug mode that the **IDataTablesRequest request** **object is null**.

Here is a screenshot of Google Chrome network log.

[image]

As I can see from the Network Log, the Web API is returning this exception which I have no clue about.

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"A null value was returned where an instance of IHttpActionResult was expected."
```

I am also attaching another screenshot of what my Request looks like from Google Chrome's network log.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `webapi controller` method is expecting an object of type `IDataTablesRequest` while sending ajax call to `webapi` you are not sending anything.

You need to send `IDataTablesRequest object` using `data` parameter of `ajax`.You can create an object of `IDataTablesRequest` using `Object` in javascript and send to webapi.

```
var request = new Object();
request.Length = 10;
request.Start = 1;
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {
    "url": "/api/StudentsBasicInfo/GetPaginatedStudentsList2",
    "data": request
  }
});
```

You also may need to set `property type` as `POST` of `ajax` if you have decorated your webapi method as `HttpPost`.

For more details you can check below links

https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data

https://cmatskas.com/server-side-jquery-datatables-with-asp-net/