# DataTables do not send ajax request at the initialization

Tags: javascript, datatables

How to use dataTables to instantiate the table does not load data (server mode),then loading data when i click on a button.If serverSide is set to true at initialization, the table will automatically send an ajax request, then render the data, which is not what I want !:(

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: don't use the datatable ajax, use a separate one associated with the button to fire it off

Comment: Did you write the datatable initialisation code on button event ? I

Comment: @HaseenaPA I just want the Datatables do not send ajax request when initialization, I think it maybe have a option to complete . but i 'm not found in [link](https://datatables.net/reference/api)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828790/jquery-datatables-ajax-request-not-hitting-web-api-correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the source code for half a day, I finally found a solution. First I needed a custom parameter called firstAjax and set it to false. like this:

```
$("#example").DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: 'your url'
    },
    firstAjax: false
});
```

Then I changed the

```
_fnReDraw (settings);  //in datatables.js line 4717
```

to

```
if (settings.oInit.firstAjax) {
         _ fnReDraw (settings);
     }
```

If the compressed js file(datatables.min.js), you should find _fnReDraw function corresponding alias.

Comment: i'm so sorry,after carefully reading the documentation found, Datatables that there are a configuration item to control the Ajax request occurs when the initialization table, this option is 'deferLoading'.

Answer (score 1):

You should use "iDeferLoading" : 0 in DataTables parameters, when you initialize it:

```
var table =  $("#table").dataTable({
  "bProcessing": true,
  "bServerSide": true,
  "iDeferLoading": 0,
  "sAjaxSource": service_url,
  "sServerMethod": "POST",
  ...
  ...
```

(or "deferLoading":0 for newer DataTables versions, 1.10 and above),
and then add the event to your button:

```
$("#button").on("click", function (event) {
   $('#table').dataTable().fnDraw();
});
```

https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html

Answer (score 0):

in a similar situation, this is how I did it.

```
         <script>
                $(function ($) {
                    $("#tbl").DataTable({columns:[{data:"id"}, {data:"text"}], dom: "tB", buttons: [{ text: "Load Me", action: function (e, dt, node, config) { loadme(e, dt, node, config); } }] });
                }
                );

                // // parameters are passed from the datatable button event handler
                function loadme(e, dt, node, config) {
                    parms = JSON.stringify({ parm1: "one", parm2: "two" });

                    $.ajax({
                        // my test web server that returns an array of {id:"code field", text:"country namee"}
                        url: "WebService1.asmx/GetAList",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ s: parms }),
                        type: 'post',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        // this is just away of passing arguments to the success handler
                        context:{dt:dt, node:node},

                        success: function (data, status) {

                            var contries = JSON.parse(data.d);
                            for (var i = 0; i < contries.length; i++){
                                this.dt.row.add(contries[i], "id", "text");
                                this.dt.draw();
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (one, two) {
                            debugger;
                        }
                    });

                }


            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div style="width:500px">
                <table id="tbl">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Code</th>
                            <th>Contru</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                    <tfoot></tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: Your code does not automatically appended DataTables's Sent Parameters, thank you very much, then maybe I should think about how to DataTables spliced to the Sent parameters S-parameters inside.@Bindrid

Comment: So, if I understand you right, after the data is fetched, you want the parameters used to fetch the data to show up as part of the data.  At the top or at the bottom of the dataset?

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution, in the initialization make like this, with the "oLanguage":

```
$('.table').dataTable({
  oLanguage: {
     sUrl: ""
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

After initialize `datatables` with ajax, use this simple line to call ajax for get data:

```
$('#table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

this code may not working with old versions of `datatables`.

Download latest version: https://datatables.net/download